# How to use Friz Quadrata font

Tags: fonts

I can use the Friz Quadrata font to write documents in LaTeX? If so, how? I have long sought a solution in the web, but I found nothing.
I'm using TexWorks 0.46

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a TTF font. AFAIK, if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you should be able to use it without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want to use the free version here: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/quadrat-serial/regular/

Download the `.ttf`- or `.otf`-file, install it (depending on your OS) and then run the following with Lua- or XeLaTeX.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Name Of Font}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the site to which you link is distributing the font illegally.  For a free clone that is legal, see https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/quadrat-serial/regular/

Comment: @Thérèse Do you think? How do you see that? This was, of course, not done by purpose. If you think, it is not legal, I will adapt my answer.

Comment: The site has a reputation for distributing malware (see https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/ufonts.com), and it distributes as free many fonts for which reputable sites sell expensive licenses.  Some foundries have released fonts into the public domain (e.g., the URW fonts which became the foundation for the TeX Gyre fonts), but ufonts.com offers no evidence that it is distributing fonts with the approval of their foundry or their designer.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you, I have removed the link.